# How to check if file is tar file in Bash shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement

My question is about Bash, Shell. I am writing a script and I have the following problem:
I have a case when user declares that he or she will extract a file into a dir. But I have to test if the existence and if exist a need to check if that file is a *.tar file. I searched for similar like when checking if the file is executable:

```
if [ -x "file" ]; then
 echo "file is executable"
else
 echo "file is not executable"

# will this if test work?
case $1
"--extract")
 if [ -e $2 ] && [ tar -tzf $2 >/dev/null ]; then
  echo "file exists and is tar archive"
 else
  echo "file either does not exists or it is not .tar arcive"
 fi
;;
esac
```

Code from above doesn't work it is totally ignored. Any ideas?

Comment: Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001709/how-to-check-if-a-unix-tar-gz-file-is-a-valid-file-without-uncompressing

Comment: That link is good stuff. You can parse the output of `file yourfile.tar` or you could look at the extension `"${filename##*.}"` but I that top answer where you just attempt to extract the tar is the most fail-safe way of doing this.

Comment: The code is missing a closing `fi`. The code should not run. Also see [How to use Shellcheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](https://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[file](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file) command can determine file type:

```
file my.tar
```

if it is a **tar** file it will output:

```
my.tar: POSIX tar archive (GNU)
```

Then you can use grep to check the output (whether or not contains *tar archive*):

```
file my.tar | grep -q 'tar archive; && echo "I'm tar" || echo "I'm not tar"
```

In case the file does not exis, file output will be (with exit code 0):

```
do-not-exist.txt: cannot open `do-not-exist.txt' (No such file or directory).
```

You could use a case statement to handle several types of files.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, if I am using case $1 and the user selects extract action and passes the file name as a parameter can I just $2 my.tar.gz. And If I need to check if a file exists and is tar simultaneously can I write:
    if [ -x $2 ] && [ $2 my.tar.gz ]; then
     echo "File exists and it is .tar"

Comment: You should show how `file` describes a non-compressed tar file.

Comment: This answer doesn't address tar files at all; it just identifies Gzip archives.

Comment: The output for tar files is '**my.tar: POSIX tar archive (GNU)**' and for non existing  files is '**do-not-exist.txt: cannot open `do-not-exist.txt' (No such file or directory)**' with exit code 0. You could use a case statement to handle several cases

Comment: Just updated the answer to use .tar files instead of .tar.gz as suggested by @chepner

Answer (score 2):

I would just see if tar can list the file:

```
if ! { tar ztf "$file" || tar tf "$file"; } >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "$file is not a tar file"
fi
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the `z` option only affects the `create` operation in most modern tar implementations. When listing (`-t`) or extracting (`-x`), tar will autodetect whether decompression is required in order to read the file. (This is at least the case with GNU tar and bsdtar in FreeBSD and macOS.)

Answer (score 1):

I usually use a construct like this based off of the `file` command.

***gzipped tarballs***

```
$ file somefile1.tar.gz | grep -q 'gzip compressed data' && echo yes || echo no
yes

$ file somefile2.tar.gz | grep -q 'gzip compressed data' && echo yes || echo no
no
```

***tarballs***

The above handles gzipped tarball files, for uncompressed change out the string that `grep` detects:

```
$ file somefile1.tar | grep -q 'POSIX tar archive' && echo yes || echo no
yes

$ file somefile2.tar | grep -q 'POSIX tar archive' && echo yes || echo no
no
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the answer. I know that this is not most optimal, however, it works as I intended.

I put `case $1` from user into a variable and create another variable equal to `*.tar.gz` then in `if` statement I compare `var1` (string from user input) with `var2` equal to `*tar.gz` and it works.

Comment: `.tgz` is also used for compressed tar files